# How to recursively check if a string is palindrome in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a recursive ruby function that returns true if a user enters a string  that is palindrome, and false otherwise.

I am also trying to have a base case for the return value

Comment: That doesn't look like ruby?

Comment: You are pretty far away from your goal, considering this is a counter function. In Java. Coded badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smells like homework assignment since you specifically request a recursive solution.

A solution with recursion is to check whether first equals last letter and if they are recursively check the string in between. An empty or one character string is a palindrome.

```
def palindrome?(str)
    str.length <= 1 or (str[0,1] == str[-1,1] and palindrome?(str[1..-2]))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

ruby! ;)

```
def palindrom?(string)
  string == string.reverse
end
```

Comment: You got two out of three words of the title, but missed "recursive" it seems…

Comment: looked like he has no clue about ruby and why over engineering this stuff if its one line?

Comment: 'cause it was clearly homework, I guess. ;-)

Comment: haha, damn you're right, point taken :)

Comment: Could be an interview question...  I've had all sorts of interview questions like this so now i study "recursive" interview questions before I go for interviews...  that said these types of questions aren't very good at determining anything.